# How to create a new column based on time difference of two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with Time_x and Time_y in the format of:

```
# 2015-10-01 23:59:59.997
%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f
```

I can't do just:

```
df['TimeDiff'] = datetime.strptime(df['Time_x'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') - \
                 datetime.strptime(df['Time_y'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

And I can't do this in order to return the difference:

```
# Defining a function to call with Pandas to apply()
def time_difference(a):
    Time_x, Time_y = a
    c = datetime.strptime(Time_x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.strptime(Time_y, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')

    if c.days < 1:
        if c.minute <= 15:
            return c.minute
        else:
            return c.days
    else:
        None

# Creating a new column using my function.
# Error: “Too many values to unpack” Exception
df['TimeDiff'] = df[['Time_x', 'Time_y']].apply(time_difference)
```

So, how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, and you're reading data from a csv file as:

```
time_x,time_y
2015-10-01 23:59:59.997,2015-10-01 23:58:59.997
2015-10-01 23:57:59.997,2015-10-01 23:59:59.997
```

I would read and parse the dates:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', parse_dates=['time_x','time_y'])
```

so you can later apply:

```
df['TimeDiff'] = (df['time_x'] - df['time_y']).dt.seconds
```

which returns:

```
                   time_x                  time_y  TimeDiff
0 2015-10-01 23:59:59.997 2015-10-01 23:58:59.997        60
1 2015-10-01 23:57:59.997 2015-10-01 23:59:59.997     86280
```

In this way you can specify the time unit desired (`dt.hour`, `dt.minute` etc).

Comment: Just for reference, I am reading data from a csv using pd.read_csv.  df.info() shows: Time_x  and Time_y as object.

Comment: After using parse_dates I see Time_x  as datetime64[ns]. Awesome!

Comment: Looks good! The performance decreased (1M+ rows in my df), but I assume that's now because the datatype is storing more data as date versus object. I also forgot to mention that Time_x, Time_y was in result of pd.merge. I parsed the dates on the original and the merge copied the data type automatically. I assume now, I can use the same time difference logic on merge to filter only the time difference in seconds to reduce my df size too.